# 7x7 matrix got integer overflow

Tags: math, matrix, integer, conditional-statements, overflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mvYF.jpg)Last time I was working on a 7x7 matrix to find the product of a positive number. I got a negative result and after putting some space it fixed. As I found out that I was an integer overflow. What was the problem actually I didn't understand? Any thoughts about it how it happened or how it fixed.

Comment: Can you please provide with more information. From the exact action you are trying to perform. What language? Can you attach the main part of the code? The error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What exactly does "find the product of a positive number" mean? We need much more information before we can help you.

Comment: I was working in c. I can't because the problem was solved but I don't understand how it happened cuz I didn't do anything important. In what cases integer overflow can happen. Btw I wasn't working with big numbers

Comment: @DanielNudelman I uploaded the photo

Answer (score 0):

I think that what would solve your problem is using `unsigned int` instead of just `int`.
Specifically for you code use

```
unsigned int sum = 1;
```

In case you want to know what is the limit of your types you can use the `sizeof()` method. Usually for `int`, it will return 2 or 4 (bytes). In case of 2 bytes your limit is 32,768. In most cases it will be 4 bytes with a limit of 2,147,483,648. If you know that you are going to work with only positive numbers you better use `unsigned int`. In this way you gain twice more options and the limits become 65,536 and 4,294,967,296 respectfully.‬

And if you think that these limits are not enough for your calculation you should consider to change the `int` type to `long`. It's size is 8 bytes and it gives you more than enough.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it